# Displaying "No results" message when manually fetching with React Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

So this is the first time I try to use React Query for manually fetching data, I'm building a simple Weather Forecast App and I did encounter a small "problem":

What I want is that when for some reason (for example, user inputs something crazy) data is not available, then display a "No results found" message.

The thing is the first time the component mounts, the React Query's data state will be undefined so I can't rely on that for displaying the No results message as it will show up even when someone is accessing for the first time to the app... Any ideas how can I display that message only when data is not available?

Here is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import Form from "./components/Form.jsx";
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from './api/httpRequest';
import Card from "./components/Card";


function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const { data: info, isFetching, isError, refetch } = useQuery("info",
    () => fetchData(search), {
    enabled: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });


  console.log(info);

  return (

    <main className="App">
      <h1 className="app-title">Weather Forecast App</h1>
      <Form search={search} setSearch={setSearch} fetch={refetch} />
      {isFetching ? "Loading..." : isError ? "Error!" : !info ? "No results" : <Card forecast={info} />}
    </main>

  );
}

export default App;
```

These are the fetching functions:

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_WEATHER = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?";
const API_WEATHER_EXCLUDE = "&exclude=minutely,hourly,alerts";
const API_COORDINATES = "http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?";

const getCoordinates = async (query) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_COORDINATES + "access_key=" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_COORDS_KEY + "&query=" + query + "&limit=1");
        return response.data.data[0];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const fetchData = async (query) => {
    try {
        const coords = await getCoordinates(query);
        const response = await axios.get(API_WEATHER + "lat=" + coords.latitude + "&lon=" + coords.longitude + API_WEATHER_EXCLUDE + "&appid=" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_WEATHER_KEY);
        return response.data;

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the value of info when there is no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the status state `(status === 'success')` instead of isFetching, like stated in the [documentations](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/queries):

```
function Todos() {
   const { status, data, error } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
 
   if (status === 'loading') {
     return <span>Loading...</span>
   }
 
   if (status === 'error') {
     return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
   }
 
   // also status === 'success', but "else" logic works, too
   return (
     <ul>
       {data.map(todo => (
         <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

I am not sure about your way of handling the returned data overall. I think it would be better to check the returned results not with `!info` because it can return a JSON data with other miscellaneous data along with am empty data for example.

Comment: That helped a lot, I used status to check for the fetching success and then I checked for the length of one of the properties of the response object (daily forecast array).

Comment: or you could just check info if it is not undefined (!info)  and then check the length of one of its props.

Comment: This answer is great but since react-query can load data from cache if there is a background error, you can also [check for data-availability first](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/status-checks-in-react-query#background-errors) and check for errors last, so the user always sees data, but it depends on your use cases